# How to String Split in javascript

Tags: javascript, split

I have a string

> fullName = 'Ross beddy washington andres'

I need to split this in to firstName, middleName and lastName.

Rule to split the names:

when receiving 2 words: 1st LastName /  firstName

when receiving 3 words: 1st LastName / 2nd LastName / firstName

when receiving 4 words: 1st LastName / 2nd LastName / firstName/ MiddleName

when receiving 5 or more than 5 words follow the rule for 4 words

For above example below will be the output:

> firstName = washington

> middleName = andres

> lastName = Ross beddy

my code:

```js
        
const fullName = 'Ross beddy washington andres';
const names = {};
const nameSplit = fullName.split(' ');
if (nameSplit.length == 4) {
    names.firstName = nameSplit[2];
    names.lastName = nameSplit[0] + ' ' + nameSplit[1];
    names.middleName = nameSplit[3];

} else if (nameSplit.length == 3) {
    names.firstName = nameSplit[2];
    names.lastName = nameSplit[0] + ' ' + nameSplit[1];
    names.middleName = '';           
} else if (nameSplit.length == 2){
    names.firstName = nameSplit[1];
    names.lastName = nameSplit[0] ;
    names.middleName = ''
}
console.log(names);
```

How to include the logic if there are more than 4 words ? is there any elegant way to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array manipulation methods to achieve this.

```js
const fullName = 'Ross beddy washington andres';
const nameSplit = fullName.split(' ');

const names = {};

if (nameSplit.length >= 2) {
  if (nameSplit.length === 2) {
    names.lastName = nameSplit[0];
    names.firstName = nameSplit[1];
    names.middleName = '';
  } else if (nameSplit.length === 3) {
    names.lastName = nameSplit[0] + ' ' + nameSplit[1];
    names.firstName = nameSplit[2];
    names.middleName = '';
  } else if (nameSplit.length === 4) {
    names.lastName = nameSplit[0] + ' ' + nameSplit[1];
    names.firstName = nameSplit[2];
    names.middleName = nameSplit[3];
  } else {
    names.lastName = nameSplit.slice(0, -2).join(' ');
    names.firstName = nameSplit[nameSplit.length - 2];
    names.middleName = nameSplit[nameSplit.length - 1];
  }
} else {
  console.log('Invalid name format');
}

console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks almost correct, but you need to handle the case when there are 5 or more words in the name. According to your rules, you should treat it as if there are 4 words. Here's an updated version of your code:

```js
const fullName = 'Ross beddy washington andres';
const names = {};
const nameSplit = fullName.split(' ');

if (nameSplit.length >= 4) {
    names.firstName = nameSplit[2];
    names.middleName = (nameSplit.length === 4) ? nameSplit[3] : '';
    names.lastName = nameSplit.slice(0, 2).join(' ');
} else if (nameSplit.length === 3) {
    names.firstName = nameSplit[2];
    names.middleName = '';
    names.lastName = nameSplit.slice(0, 2).join(' ');
} else if (nameSplit.length === 2) {
    names.firstName = nameSplit[1];
    names.middleName = '';
    names.lastName = nameSplit[0];
} else {
    console.log("Invalid input");
}

console.log(names);
```

This code checks if the length of nameSplit is greater than or equal to 4 and treats it as 4 words according to your rules. Otherwise, it follows your original logic for 3 words and 2 words. Additionally, it handles the case when the input doesn't match any of these scenarios by printing "Invalid input."

Comment: ChatGPT is [banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned) at SO. Please write your own answers

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```js
if (names.length >= 4) {
    lastName = names[0] + ' ' + names[1];
    firstName = names[2];
    middleName = names.slice(3).join(' ');
}
```

If the names array has more than 4 elements, the middleName variable is assigned the value of all the remaining elements in the names array, joined together into a string using the join method.